# One to many, and one to one combined? Django

Tags: sql, django

```
class Inquiry(models.Model):
    inquiry_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    inquiry_desc = models.CharField('Inquiry', max_length=5000)

class Customer(models.Model):
    cust_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    inquiry_id = models.ForeignKey(Inquiry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cust_f_name = models.CharField('Customer First Name', max_length=50)
    cust_l_name = models.CharField('Customer Last Name', max_length=50)
    cust_street = models.CharField('Customer Street', max_length=50)
    cust_city = models.CharField('Customer City', max_length=50)
    cust_state = models.CharField('Customer State', max_length=50)
    cust_zip = models.CharField('Customer Zip Code', max_length=10)
```

Hi there!

I am trying to model a one to many (a customer may have many inquiries) and a one to one (an inquiry may have one customer).

Here are my difficulties/what I have tried so far:

1. Inquiries as foreign key in Customer model. This works fine, however, you can only assign one inquiry object per customer. I would like to assign several (so Inquiry1, inquiry2, inquiry3, etc) to the customer. 
   [image]
2. Customer as a OneToOne field in Inquiry (thought this might work for some reason - but as OneToOne work, when I tried to add a a new Inquiry to an existing company it didn't work).

I am looking for conceptual advice to do this. I think I'm getting confused.

Thank you!

Comment: "one to one (***an inquiry may have one customer***)" - and then - "however, you can only assign ***one*** inquiry object per customer". Please explain.

Comment: I guess to be clearer with my ask:

How do I model a one to many relation in Django where the instances of the Model (say Inquiry) are grouped with the instance of Customer? Right now it has the option to select all instances of the Inquiry model.

Comment: Even though its a one to many relationship (customer can have multiple inquiries) its only allowing one in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You have it back to front. An `Inquiry` object should have a foreign key relation to a `Customer`. The reverse relation (by default `inquiry_set`) on `Customer` allows you to retrieve all inquiries received from that customer:

```
 for inquiry in customer.inquiry_set.all():
     ...
```